# XSL read value of element within a loop

Tags: xslt

I have in my xml a tag containing a list. For example:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <title>Bob Dylan</title>
        <title>USA</title>
        <title>Columbia</title>
        <title>10.90</title>
        <title>1985</title>
    </cd>

</catalog>
```

I would like with my xsl transformation to iterate through the title list and get the values of each element. I tried like this but the values are not retrieved.

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/title">
      <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I also tried with the entire XPATH to the title but it still did not work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/title">
      <title><xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd/title"/></title>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  are effectively trying to call: catalog/cd/title/title in your first example, try the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/title">
      <title><xsl:value-of select="."/></title>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one?

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You could check your code with this example: 
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp